# is it possible to view elmah error log in two projects with one authentication in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, elmah, elmah.io

I have two projects, one is web with a login page, the other is my API project which is used for routing.

I installed Elmah package in both projects and enabled authentication, so both projects errors are stored in their respective local project path

I need to view the logs with authentication in API projects, but I didn't have login and authentication logic in this project

so using web project authentication, need to view the API logs.

Is it possible?

Comment: Can't you just log to the same database from both websites? And then use the web project to browse the errors.